# Problema com script no upstart

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script

Estou tentando iniciar minha aplicação no boot, mas não estou conseguindo...o script no upstart chama outra script, eu não estou conseguindo nem saber se o 2º script está sendo chamado, segue os 2 scripts: 
 
**1º Script**

```
description "Start OpenProject"
start on startup
script
exec su openproject -c "/home/openproject/Scripts/start-openproject.sh"
end script
```

**2º Script**

```
#!/bin/bash -x

rm -f ~/server.log

source ~/.nodeenv/bin/activate >> ~/server.log 2>&1
cd /home/openproject/openproject
bundle exec rails server >> ~/server.log 2>&1
```

O arquivo server.log nem está sendo criado, desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque os dois scripts no /etc/rc.local, um abaixo do outro. O primeiro script aparentemente vai dar erro mesmo, pois usa uma sintaxe que não é do bash, parece mais um arquivo descritivo do que o segundo faz.